# div popup inside td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a bunch of cells. (No way! Amazing! :P) Some of the cells have a small div that when you put your mouse over, it gets bigger so you can read all the text. This works well and all. However, since html elements that come later in the document have a higher z-index, when the div gets bigger it is underneath the other divs in the other cells.

Some html code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    limited info
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 1em; height: 1em;" onmouseover="tooltipshow(this)" onmouseout="tooltiphide(this)">
        informative long text is here
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    some short info
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 1em; height: 1em;" onmouseover="tooltipshow(this)" onmouseout="tooltiphide(this)">
        longer explanation about what is really going on that covers the div up there ^^^. darn!
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Some js code:

```
function tooltipshow(obj)
{
    obj.style.width = '30em';
    obj.style.zIndex = '100';
}

function tooltiphide(obj)
{
    obj.style.width = '1em';
    obj.style.zIndex = '20';
}
```

It doesn't matter if I set z-index dynamically to something higher onmouseover. It's like z-index has no affect. I think it has something to do with the table.

I've tested this in FireFox3. When I'm feeling particularly macho, I'll test it in IE.

Comment: could you by chance post some styles? i cant mimic the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting z-index and opacity were messing things up. Check this out:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td {
    background-color: #aaf;
    padding: 1em;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

div.highlight {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2em;
    /* the offenders */
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

div.tag {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5em;
    left: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 20;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    text-align: left;
    border: solid 0.1em #000;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
}

div.tag:hover {
    width: 30em;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    limited info
    <div class="relative">
    <div class="highlight">
      <div class="tag">
        informative long text is here
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    some short info
    <div class="relative">
    <div class="highlight">
      <div class="tag">
        aaaaaaaaaalolkjlkjnger explanation about what is really going on that covers the div up there ^^^. darn!
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a CSS-based solution?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    limited info
    <div class="details">
      <div>
        informative long text is here
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    some short info
    <div class="details">
      <div>
        longer explanation about what is really going on that covers the div up there ^^^. darn!
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.details {
    position: relative;
}
.details div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
.details div:hover {
    width: 30em;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

If Javascript is necessary, you can change the `.details div:hover {` line to `.show-details {` and apply the class to the element using `element.className = 'show-details';`

Comment: +1 Thanks for the CSS hover tip. It looks like the problem I was having was related to z-index and opacity. z-index is a odd, but I may not understand it fully. However, the opacity problem is just strange. I think that is a bug in FF. Oh well, now to wrestle with IE... Yuck.

Comment: You ought to try tinkering with z-index at 100% opacity to get a feel for z-index before making things translucent.

Comment: Yeah, but even at 0.99 I still get the problem. So it's not my eyes. With either z-index or opacity set to anything other than 1, it is covered. In this case I cannot use opacity at all because if this "bug". At least I think it is a bug. Removing the z-index AND the opacity works. If either are there, I get the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same HTML/CSS from @Kevin answer, but change the z-index of the relative div `.details` as well. This will work better on IE.